Laptop fan runs in sleeping mode: Can anyone teach me how to set up my power plan?
My laptop fan never runs when on battery supply. But if I plug in power, then it will run sometimes. But when I leave laptop a few minutes without action, it will run loudly, and I know it has something to do with power performance but I can't find useful solution so far.
My power option seems a little bit different from what some people post on the internet.
Can anyone teach me how to set up my power plan?


This doesn't seem to be a problem with the power plan. If you haven't installed a program to use your CPU for good purposes while idle, this might be an infection. Do deep antivirus scans using Defender and Malwarebytes.

I didn't find any virus and it is quite strange that fan never runs when in battery mode. so I don't think it virus. it's my confuguration

Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

This is likely because of a feature called Windows Modern Standby: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHKKcd3sx2c
Previously, you could turn off this feature in the power menu. But Microsoft killed that option and unfortunately, it's not possible to toggle this anymore.
